# Jinja2 template engine if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, jinja2

`unit['flag']` is either an integer or a unicode value. `subscription` is an array of unicode values.

I am trying to see if `unit['flag']` is in the subscriptions array. If it is I wanna put `'checked'` there so the checkbox could  be checked.

For some reason it doesn't work:

For example, I print subscription which is [u'1', u'2', u'3'], and unit['flag'] is '1' and checked never shows up in the HTML code

```html
 <td><input type="checkbox" 

    {%if unit['flag'] in subscription%} 
    checked
    {%endif%}
    onclick="x()" > </a>

</td>
```

Comment: Define *it doesn't work*. You get an error message? Or `checked` just never shows up? How certain are you that `unit['flag']` contains a value that is actually also in `subscription`?

Comment: are you *100% certain* that `unit['flag']` is not an integer or something like that?

Comment: Just print the contents of the values above in the webpage...

Comment: conversion worked! 
unit['flag'] | string
Thank you!